# how to convert PI to openWRT

Tags: openwrt

right im really new to openWRT and seems to be loads of windy docs out there, so basically im looking for some quick answers.

my simple questions ;) are:

1. can i convert my Pi to OpenWRT
2. when Converted can i have OpenWRT use DHCP
3. is it possible to have a SSL client configured which is automatic, so basically try to connect to openwisp2 without Manuel input?
4. can this be configured on GNS3

i know the questions are very basic but i like to start at a very high level and not drown before i try even build this.

thanks

joe

Comment: `can this be configured on GNS3` ... can what be configured on GNS3?

Comment: Guess you'll have to read the windy docs after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Please see [the offical documentation at openwrt.org](https://openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi_foundation/raspberry_pi). In short: Download the image file linked there, put it onto the SD card, boot the Pi.
2. Yes. Please see the OpenWrt documentation, as your Pi is an OpenWrt router then.
3. Yes. See [this documentation at OpenWISP](http://openwisp.io/docs/user/configure-device.html).
4. *I think so — really no idea.* It's not a Raspberry thing. Please check anything OpenWrt how to do that.